# UK Visitor Visa Refuse at the border

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, malaysian-citizens

I was refused at the border in Heathrow Airport on the 18th May because I did not book a return ticket as I intend to continue my journey to Europe and then homeward (Malaysia) thereon. I wanted to visit family and friends for 5 months on a visa-free passport and I have one set of family in the UK and another set of extended family back home sponsoring my time in the UK. But I was said to lie about it and was detained for 8 hours until the exact flight fly me back to where I come from. My family have no idea that I was at the airport because I was planning to head to the train station and give them a surprise welcome. But now the whole family was completely distraught by the entire dilemma.

During the interview and the decision-making interview, the Immigration Officer (IO) told me that I could return to the UK the very next day after removal *if* I come back with a return ticket and I stay only for one month. (Please note that I carry roughly GBP1,300 cash in hand and I also have GBP5,000 in my home bank account.) Since I come from a visa-free country, the IO told me that I do not require a visa to re-enter the UK if I do as instructed.

After the incident, I have to admit that I have been completely foolish not to get a return ticket in the first place and stay longer than likened. Due to that, I received an X on my passport and it really saddened me to know that I will face issue at the border in future. In fact, I do want to return to the UK on the 2nd June because I have friends and informal meetings lining up as promised; and I would also love to meet my family from the other side of the world as well. I have not seen them for almost 8 years now. Since they are my family, obviously they have prepared a room, food and transport for my time in the UK and all these are naturally well-taken care of. Therefore I actually do not need to bring much money into the country. But I still bring some anyway just in case I wanted to get something along the way especially when I am alone.

During the time when I arrived home on the 21st May (3 days after the incident), I booked a return ticket with the duration of a month to the UK, asked my dad (I am working for him) to help me issue an annual leave letter to notify the UK border that I am working for him and I do have a job back home, got my family in UK to give me all their personal contact and even ask the host for all his personal details in case I got asked at the border.

I still have a week to go. I read that it is recommended that we get a visa to clear the "black mark" but I kept remembering the IO saying that there is no need to get a visa because I am from a visa-free country. I just need to change the situation and return if desire.

My family in the UK are now looking forward to my arrival on the 2nd June and this time round, they will wait for me at the airport; and if required, they are prepared to claim me from the authority if needed because they, too, wanted me to visit them very much. In fact, they told me to get to Manchester instead as it is nearer to where they are and there are lesser people; obviously more time to sort things out with the IO regarding to my case.

My question is: Will I get refusal again? Even after I change my circumstance?

I have the return ticket already and it is of one-month stay. I have an approval annual leave letter. I have my Fixed Deposit (FD) statement with me as my parents now doesn't bank in money to me thru normal transaction but just add on the amount into my FD, I still carry GBP1,300 of cash in hand, my family in the UK has given me all the answer that I might get asked at the border later on.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your writeup is too long. Make it concise.

Comment: I'd recommend asking a different question. We're not border officers, we can't tell if you will get refused or not.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for/89879#89879. In my estimation it is more likely than not that you’re turned away. You seem desperate **and more importantly** you’re not very articulate and very verbose and appear to lack the [personal impact and articulation skills](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/what-is-meant-by-personal-impact-and-articulation-skills-in-the-context-of-bor) required to be successful in a face to face with a hostile immigration officer

Comment: "the Immigration Officer (IO) told me that I could return to the UK the very next day after removal if I come back with a return ticket and I stay only for one month. " Why does that not answer your question?

Comment: Per https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47180/refused-entry-to-uk-not-sure-what-to-do, thegolden advice is to apply foran entry visa after refused entry.

Comment: @DJClayworth I am not sure if the change of circumstances will allowed me into the UK even though I am very sure that is exactly what the IO said. I have not been to the UK for 1.5 years so I really want to go back and meet my family and friends.

Comment: @RedBaron: But the IO said there is no need for that because I am holding a visa-free passport. Even with the entry clearance, the desk counter will know the truth.

Comment: As noted in answer to that question - " it is not required, but a highly recommended option". The same advice has been found for other similar cases on this site (you can search for questions with uk and visas tag). You will mention the removal from port while applying visa (and all subsequent visits if asked). Once you obtain a visa and visit UK using that visa, you can use visa free access on subsequent visits.