# Taking 2 laptops and an iPad for travel, as a student, to South Korea from USA

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, south-korea

I'm a US Citizen who has received a D-2 (Student) South Korean Visa.  I have one laptop that I use for personal/school use and another laptop I that I am required by my job to use on their system (which is still personal use). I also have an iPad that I was planning to bring along for personal use.  Will carrying this many devices be an issue when traveling to South Korea or when I return to the US in December?

(The job is an entirely online position that is for a company in the US and will only be paying me through my US bank)

Comment: [In most countries working there would mean you need a work permit – no matter for whom you work and where you are paid](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/where-can-i-travel-for-prolonged-periods-of-time-while-legally-working-remotely) (don't know about Korea though, maybe your student visa allows that). Having a second work laptop with you but claiming it's for personal use is highly suspicious. Additionally flagging to move the question to Expatriates as this question is about moving there and not travel.

Comment: @neo I am only traveling for 4 months.  I'm not making any permanent residency.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "December" part. My point still stands: Claiming a work laptop as "personal use"  (instead of "business use") doesn't make you look good at the border. I won't add an answer below as I don't know about Korea specifically but almost everywhere working requires explicit permission even if it's a foreign employer and the income is paid to an foreign account (also look out for possible taxation in Korea). Having a second laptop with you would maybe let them look twice and starting to question you. The problem wouldn't be the laptop but rather that you intend to work.

Comment: South Korea is a normal developed country and you will not likely face any opposition at the airport.

Comment: Basically, I flew to South Korea about 10 years ago. My luggage loadout was along the following lines: two notebooks, a videocamera, a photocamera, a music player, a couple external HDDs and flash drives. No out-of-the-ordinary questions asked at any border crossing at the airport.

Comment: Despite "not making any permenant residency" doesn't change the fact that it's almost certainly illegal to do paid work in Korea (even for a US company paying you in the US) while visiting on a student visa, and if discovered may get you in a lot of trouble.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Being a 'normal developed country' has nothing to do with the border forces and entry rules. What neo has said is true. If the OP takes two laptops, and tells the interviewer, if asked, that one of them was issued for work by his online company, the interviewer will look at his _student_ visa and may be like "why do you have a work laptop if you're a student?"

Answer (score 2):

This question makes some assumptions that may be (are) erroneous. Carrying two laptops from the US and into South Korea, and then back to the US several months later isn't, or shouldn't be, of concern to either Customs or Border Protection of either the US or South Korea. In these days of online connectivity, many of us travel with multiple electronic devices all the time. I carry a laptop, a tablet, a smartphone (android), many flash drives and memory chips, and I am lighter than many I know.

Your problem will be if you do get flagged for interview in S. Korea, by Border Protection, and if you tell them truthfully (and you should *always always always* be truthful, because being caught in a lie will cause you to be flagged from further travel, at the very least), that one of your laptops is for working an online job, then you are admitting you will be working while in the country on a student visa.

Just because it's an online company, and the work you do from them can be done from anywhere, does not mean it is legal to do everywhere. If you are earning income inside a country, you may be expected/required to pay taxes on the foreign earned income. The fact you are working, at all, may or may not be allowed while on a student visa.