# Refused entry to UK twice

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visas-on-arrival, removal

In February 2015 I travelled to the UK. The 'travel website' said I didn't need a visa to stay for up to 90 days. I was refused entry but allowed to stay for 4 days with my friend there. I travelled back in June and the same thing happened this time I only planned on staying for a month. Same thing happened a grueling 6 hour interrogation and given 4 days to stay and sent back.
I'd like to travel over again but would like to be assured of being allowed to stay for the time I choose before I make arrangements to fly over again. WHat if anything can I do to cover all my bases.

Comment: Is it a long-distance relationship?

Comment: The simplest answer: apply for and get a visa.

Comment: What travel website did you consult? The advice "visa not needed for stays of up to 90 days" sounds like it's for the Schengen area, which the UK isn't part of, so something seems not quite right here.

Comment: We need much more context. Why were you removed? What "travel website"? and most importantly what is your citizenship?

Comment: Guessing, as the OP hasn't given us enough info yet, but it could be an effective duplicate of this: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65219/refused-leave-to-enter-at-gatwick-airport-uk-and-subsequently-removed/ (right down to asking for entry on a basis that doesn't exist)

Comment: Wow, yes, if the OP is in an LDR then about 80% of that answer will suffice, the only difference is the other OP got removed whereas this OP got a TA, otherwise a clear match.

Comment: @CMaster, (or anybody else) if not a duplicate then feel free to adapt the central theme of that answer into one here. The major portions will be the same almost word-for-word. A piece of cake really.

Comment: Hello I'm sorry I didn't give enough information. It was the website from the airline I used Cheapo Air. I am a US citizen and from everything I've been reading it appears that US UK 'relations' aren't as friendly as that website said.

Comment: Not clear why the first time and was told they'd keep doing it 2nd time 'not enough money' Just a friend