# UK citizen on ESTA traveling to USA with a land trip to Canada, any problems?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, esta, uk-citizens

> Your travel authorization has been approved and you are authorized to
>   travel to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program.

So I've been accepted onto the Visa Waiver Program/ESTA. I've been to America before on a separate ESTA in 2015 with no problems. But this time I plan to take a trip into Canada for a few days with my America friend in his car while I'm over in America.

Flying in and out of JFK on both ends of my overall trip, trip is 3 weeks long overall, just wondering will I have to get another visa to enter Canada? Will I have to pay a fee for reentry to USA, or get another visa to enter back into the USA?

Comment: Which of the two are you planning to leave from?  Will you be alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't have an issue (barring the usually caveats about eligibility for entry into Canada etc).

The ESTA is just required for you to fly to the US - you enter under the Visa Waiver Program, which will give you 90 days (or shorter if the Customs and Border Protection officer deems it necessary to limit your trip - you can mitigate this by explaining your plans to him).

You do not need an ESTA or an ETA (Canadian version of the ESTA) to travel to Canada via ground or sea, it's for entry via air only.

As a British citizen, you enjoy the ability to request a visa at the Canadian border, which you shouldn't have an issue with unless you have outstanding issues with Canadian immigration or police.

You don't have to pay a fee at either border, and so long as you stay under 90 days total (or whatever shorter limit the CBP officer sticks you with) between the two countries you should be let back into the US without any concerns at all.

Comment: Awesome! Just out of interest, would I get a passport stamp for going to Canada, and/or another for entry back into the US?

Comment: @LukeXF Im not entirely sure about the US re-entry stamp, but I did get a stamp going into Canada last May on a British passport.  You could always ask the CBP official at the US-Canadian border specifically for a stamp - they could refuse, but they won't deny you entry for asking!

Comment: Note that it is *not* fee-free if you do it the other way around, as I did in 2016. The US will charge you $6 for a I-94W form that they will staple in your passport and the Canadian side will then remove it when you go back to Canada. You should still have no problems crossing the border though as a UK citizen.

Comment: "request a visa at the Canadian border": this is incorrect.  Rather, British citizens are among those who can enter Canada for certain purposes without a visa.  Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @phoog visa, entry clearance with limits, its all the same at the end of the day :) A decision is made, leave to enter is granted, limits are set in both instances...

Comment: @Moo in the UK, in any event, people sometimes get themselves into trouble by misunderstanding the terminology and the related procedures (see, for example, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65219/19400).  Perhaps the Canadians are more laid back.

Comment: @Moo I was able to get in just fine. Canadian border control gave me a stamp in my passport so I was very happy. American border control was grumpy and rude with no stamp - exactly what I expected haha.