# Do I need a visa to work for my company in Europe whilst holidaying in New Zealand?

Tags: visas, air-travel, international-travel, new-zealand

My Europe-based company has offered to allow me to work during my holidays in New Zealand which would really help out.

I go there the 1st June.

Do I need a special visa or is a tourist one OK?

Comment: Further to this, are there any countries nearby (i.e in Asia) that would allow me to work for my country at home without Visa ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm living in NZ, what I can see from my experience if your company is Europe-based and you come to NZ with a tourist/visitor visa and you work remotely with your computer for that company then, there wouldn't be any problem.

Now the problem is if you come to NZ and you are trying to work for a NZ company and or doing some freelance job here, then you need a work visa for that and you have to pay taxes.

NZ Immigration website: https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas

Comment: There is no way the asker can trust this answer without any additional sources.

Comment: What do you mean @immibis ?

Comment: 1) I mean that I would not trust the advice of some random stranger on the Internet regarding immigration law, unless they *at least* showed me a relevant page on the relevant immigration authority's website, and 2) asking someone if they're a troll is very impolite.

Comment: This might help then: https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas

Comment: It might but it doesn't. Check my [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89602/4188) to the more generic version of this for how it looks when a country allows for this: they specifically define that this sort of remote work is not considered "work" for visa purposes. I have never seen similar for New Zealand.