# Can you work online with an Indian Tourist Visa?

Tags: india, tourist-visas

I'm from the United States, and I'm planning on going to India for a few months of tourism. During that time, however, I would like to continue working for my U.S.-based company by just working online on my laptop. I'm a software developer.

Is this allowed with a Tourist Visa?

Comment: I think this question is not a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45092/4188 but the answers are highly relevant. And no, you can't do this, there are extremely few countries which allow it. It's a whole another question, one which we do not cover here whether you can be caught breaking the law.

Comment: You're Just Wrong, @chx.  It's a subtle and difficult issue.  Under India's *definition* of tourism you're saying you *know* that this is not covered and is excluded?   (Furthermore, did you realize that, in fact, an ordinary India eVisa *now includes* business activities as well as Tourism?  Have you used an India eVisa?)

Comment: yes of course! As long as your company won't mind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of putting in an answer,

## Yes

it is **absolutely, totally commonplace** for Americans, while on holiday (in France, Japan, China, India, Tasmania, or anywhere),

to work on their laptop (i.e., for their ordinary home company in the US).

Your question is literally "Can?" you do this, the answer is an overwhelming "Yes".

---

As a curiosity, note that recently the India eVisa was changed *so indeed, you can actually "do business" even, while in India*.

(Note the [checkboxes](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/Registration) where you fill in one or more purposes for informational purposes; the final stamp in your passport when you arrive is just the same.)

So in fact if for some reason you had business dealings with *an Indian company*, when you're on holiday in India, it's 10000% ok to actually go to meetings, do paperwork - even with India companies - while you're there!

There is no issue whatsoever with checking your email, writing some code, on your laptop while you're on holiday somewhere.