# US citizen making money online when in the UK as a tourist

Tags: uk, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, work, freelance

I'm an American citizen currently in the UK as a tourist. I'm aware of the limitations that this comes with, but I'm trying to figure out if it's in any way possible for me to make money online whilst being here?

Let's say for example I was making money from freelancing through something like fiverr (purely a theoretical example) whilst I was in the UK. Is this permitted? What are my limitations if so?

Comment: What's fiverr? Also, note that "visa" is an ordinary word and shouldn't be written in caps.

Comment: Hey, [fiverr](http://fiverr.com) is basically a website in which you can advertise freelancing services, such as web development or essay writing in return for payment online.

Comment: I added the [tag:standard-visitor-visas] tag to your quesiton, but U.S. citizens don't normally need a visa to enter the U.K. as a tourist. Can you clarify your status?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you're right. I should have put that I'm in the UK as a tourist, I'll update my post.

Comment: OK. I don't see why it would make any difference whether you communicated with the client online or face-to-face, but hopefully somebody can answer with some actual sources.

Comment: You don't even need to be paid to be considered as a worker but I can't find a suitable source. A tourist does not work, and freelancing is working.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered under 4.6 and 4.7 of the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

V 4.6 Permitted activities must not amount to the applicant taking employment, or doing work which amounts to them filling a role or providing short-term cover for a role within a UK based organisation. In addition, where the applicant is already paid and employed outside of the UK, they must remain so. Payment may only be allowed in specific circumstances set out in V 4.7.

V4.7 relates to not receiving payment from a UK source for any activities undertaken in the UK, with a few specific exceptions that don’t apply to the question posted.

See also the section on the UK in this question [Where can I travel for prolonged periods of time while legally working remotely for a company in my home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/where-can-i-travel-for-prolonged-periods-of-time-while-legally-working-remotely/45492#45492)