# Is some remote work now permitted for travelers admitted to the UK on a tourist entry?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, visa-free-entry, work

Users at Travel:SE have for years accepted the idea that a visitor to the UK may not use a tourist entry to “live” in the UK, and may not work remotely in the UK while visiting. The first issue seems settled, and is not the focus of this question. This question addresses only the second issue: whether a visitor to the UK may work remotely while in the UK.

Previous questions addressing this are legion, a few on Travel.StackExchange are [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142425/us-citizen-making-money-online-when-in-the-uk-as-a-tourist/142429?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C22.2309%23142429) and [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142425/us-citizen-making-money-online-when-in-the-uk-as-a-tourist/142429?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C22.2309%23142429) ; others on Expatriates.StackExchange are [this one](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17814/temporary-teleworking-1-month-abroad-while-employed-by-us-employer) and [this one](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8039/uk-immigration-is-it-legal-to-work-remotely-from-uk-as-a-dependent-of-a-spouse/17473%2317473). Yesterday, the question [My girlfriend lives in the UK and I want to be able to come and leave as I please for next 3 years—which visa should I get?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157770/my-girlfriend-lives-in-the-uk-and-i-want-to-be-able-to-come-and-leave-as-i-pleas) was posted on Travel:SE, and the answers and comments took the usual you-can’t-work-remotely-while-visiting track. No surprises there.

Then user @ZenJ posted an interesting comment. Here’s the comment:

> Actually I just found this: Immigration Rules Appendix V: visitor
> rules ([gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/…](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)) and sections 4.5-4.7
> prohibit work in UK for UK company, but allow remote work (at least
> how I understand it). In addition, where the applicant is already paid
> and employed outside of the UK, they must remain so. Next paragraph
> 4.7 prohibits payment only from UK sources

Here is the actual Guidance text in Sections 4.5, 4.6, and 4.7.

Section 4.5 addresses "Prohibited Activities"

> **Prohibited activities**
>
> **Work**
>
> V 4.5 The applicant must not intend to work in the UK, which includes the following:
>
> (a) taking employment in the UK;
>
> (b) doing work for an organisation or business in the UK;
>
> (c) establishing or running a business as a self-employed person;
>
> (d) doing a work placement or internship;
>
> (e) direct selling to the public;
>
> (f) providing goods and services;
> unless expressly allowed by the permitted activities in Appendices 3, 4 or 5.

Section 4.6 lists additional prohibitions.

> V 4.6 Permitted activities must not amount to the applicant taking
> employment, or doing work  which amounts to them filling a role or
> providing short-term cover for a role within a UK      based
> organisation. In addition, where the applicant is already paid and
> employed outside of   the UK, they must remain so. Payment may only be
> allowed in specific circumstances set out in V 4.7.

Section 4.7 addresses payment from UK sources.

> Payment V 4.7 The applicant must not receive payment from a UK source
> for any activities undertaken in the UK, except for the following:
>
> (a) reasonable expenses to cover the cost of their travel and subsistence,
> including fees for directors attending board-level meetings; or
>
> (b) prize money; or
>
> (c) billing a UK client for their time in the UK,
> where the applicant’s overseas employer is contracted to provide
> services to a UK company, and the majority of the contract work is
> carried out overseas. Payment must be lower than the amount of the
> applicant’s salary; or
>
> (d) multi-national companies who, for
> administrative reasons, handle payment of their employees’ salaries
> from the UK; or
>
> (e) where the applicant is engaged in Permitted Paid
> Engagements (PPE) as listed at Appendix 4, provided the applicant
> holds a visa or leave to enter as a PPE visitor; or
>
> (f) paid performances at a permit free festival as listed in Appendix 5.

I’m a retired lawyer in the US, and familiar with reading statutes and rules. While the [See All Updates link](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/updates) shows the Guidance’s amendment history, its format is unfamiliar to me and hard to read. This text, however, appears to have been in place for at least a year.

The text in these three sections contradicts the common knowledge we’ve shared here for years. § 4.5 contains work prohibitions, but it’s not difficult to define remote work that would not foul them. For example, a traveler employed by a non-UK firm, which firm doesn’t have a presence in the UK, sell product in the UK, or meet clients in the UK, appears to escape this section's prohibitions.

§ 4.6 is more of the same, and even contains this tidbit:

> In addition, where the applicant is already paid and employed outside
> of the UK, they must remain so.

§ 4.7 simply prohibits payment from UK sources.

All told, this looks like remote work is permitted on a tourist entry, provided the remote work doesn’t violate any of the no-nos set forth in these three sections.

For another example, consider a foreign academic, normally resident in a home country and not in the UK, employed by a home country institution in the home country, and paid in home-country currency by that non-UK institution into a home-country bank account. It appears that this individual could work remotely while a visitor in the UK without violating any of these prohibitions, provided the work consisted only (for example) of leading online classes of students who themselves all remain in the home country...further provided, of course, that the academic's presence in the UK remained as a tourist and not as one "living" in the UK.

Thus, my question: Is some remote work now permitted for travelers admitted to the UK on a tourist entry?

Comment: I think this is relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/45492/71664

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain Thanks, I agree it's relevant, and I think it supports the conclusion I posit in this question. I felt wistful for Gayot's expertise when I wrote the question, and smile at seeing him again in the question you cite.

Comment: Agreed, Gayot's answers are always a gift.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Does the prohibition on providing goods and services in V4.5(f) and the permitted activities App 3 Academics (12) apply to your academic online classes example? A ‘safe’ interpretation of the Rules is that any business activity not in App3 is not permitted.

Comment: @Traveller I think Appendix 3 no longer exists. The Guidance's Immigration Rules Index, at gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-index shows Appendix 3 as "Deleted." Notes at the head of the Index page show the Index page was originally published 25 February 2016, and updated 4 June 2020.

Comment: @Traveller As to V4.5(f), given the earlier subsections' only-within-the-UK application, it seems unlikely that (f)'s "provision of services" would include services provided  exclusively to people outside the UK.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica No, that’s not correct. There is an App3 of the Visitor Rules (and an App 2, 4 &5). It is referred to within the main body of the Visitor Rules V4.2(c) and is still available here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: @Traveller Thanks for the correction. You're right, there is a distinct App3 within the Visitor Rules, and it's still in effect. I'm not an expert in any aspect of the UK administrative rules, either in their composition or interpretation or enforcement. Still I wonder: App3 lists permissible activities for visitors. Does that mean that any activity not specifically listed is therefore impermissible and prohibited? How are these things construed in the UK?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica That’s the the way I’d interpret them, although I can’t point to any further guidance other than the examples already quoted here. In practice, I think it’s highly unlikely a tourist doing the odd hour or so of checking email, joining a conference call etc for their overseas employer from time to time while visiting would have any problems. But entering the UK purporting to be a tourist whilst actually intending to pretty much continue full normal duties for an overseas employer on a remote basis isn’t allowed (although I’d imagine lots of people do it & get away with it).

Comment: Fwiw, Academics are not a great example, as they already get a lot of exceptions.I wonder how the "self employed" thing would effect contractors too.

Comment: I've looked everywhere for this, but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer. Your best bet is to contact the UK consulate or embassy directly. When applying for the visa, ask them and be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 11):

Remote working while in the UK as a visitor is explicitly covered in the Visit Guidance published in Oct 2021 https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf#page31

**Remote working**

Visitors are permitted to undertake activities relating to their employment overseas remotely whilst they are in the UK, such as responding to emails or answering phone calls. However, you should check that the applicant’s main purpose of coming to the UK is to undertake a permitted activity, rather than specifically to work remotely from the UK. Where the applicant indicates that they intend to spend a large proportion of their time in the UK and will be doing some remote working, you should ensure that they are genuinely employed overseas and are not seeking to work in the UK.

Comment: Very good. Sounds like a restatement of your comment of June 21, 2020.

Comment: I wonder how that affects self-employed people. For example, could a novelist visit and spend time writing part of a novel while enjoying the tourist visa. With no expectation of receiving emoluments from anywhere during the stay.

Comment: @reallydismayed IANAL, however my interpretation of the guidance is that the *main purpose* of the visit should be a permitted activity. If for example the novelist wanted to split a 4 month trip between say 3 months actively researching/writing their novel (ie remote working) and 1 month visiting friends/tourist attractions, the answer might be No.