# Capital with fewest resident embassies

Tags: factoids, embassies, cities

What is the capital of country with fewest resident embassies. I have one example but will add it as answer later (if no one mention it).
By country I accept the definition and list of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states)

Comment: If this question is serious, you would have to define "country" first. There are places like Sealand which claim to be sovereign, but hardly anybody else agrees and they get **zero** embassies from serious countries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a political trivia question, with no impact on Travel.

Comment: @o.m., when you travel you may need support from embassy. So IMO it is related.

Comment: @o.m., I add my understanding of country.

Comment: Not really, because many countries have agreements in this regard. Just one EU embassy can help people from all 28 (soon to be 27) member states.

Comment: @o.m., did you try this. In most of the cases you will reach language barrier. in EU there are 24 languages so "EU embassy" may not be so helpful

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s purpose and usefulness isn’t clear and the answer is likely to change over time

Comment: @Traveller: It's a factoid question rather than a "problem I'm facing" question. It never makes much sense to me when we accept factoid questions and when we reject them. I just go along with the consensus. But as for answers that are likely to change over time, that is definitely not a reason to disallow questions here and we've discussed it over the years. Just about any practical question asked on this site has a changeable answer.

Comment: To all close voters: if my question is not appropriate here, why this one survive and become popular in SE? https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/152355/107380

Answer (score 2):

You can try beating Andorra which has a Spanish and a French embassy. And Monaco has three embassies, but only one (Malta) in the capital Monte Carlo. Your question is a bit unclear there.

Answer (score 2):

Two countries do not have **resident** embassies in capitals: Vatican and Liechtenstein. To be precise Vatican have embassies, but in Rome, not in the city itself. 
For reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_to_the_Holy_See)

Answer (score 0):

**Tiraspol**, the capital of Transnistria has no embassies.

Interestingly, Transnistria does have three embassies of its own though: Abkhazia, Russia, and South Ossetia.

**Stepanakert**, the capital of Artsakh also has no embassies.

Yes these are not widely recognized countries...

So I kept looking and found that

**Alofi**, the capital of Niue, has one high commission and no embassies. Any embassies of the country are non-resident embassies, located elsewhere.

I wouldn't be surprised if other tiny island nations also have none, but I stopped looking.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Transnistria is absolutely on your list, in "Other States" section.