# Remaining Employed in Hong Kong While in Australia on a 417 Working Holiday Visa

Tags: visas, australia, hong-kong, working-holiday, working-visas

I have applied for and obtained a type [417 Australia Working Holiday visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/417.aspx). However, should my company in Hong Kong be willing, could I continue working for them while in Australia? I can't find any material on it on the official site nor on various blogs and Q&A posts around the web.

I am a Canadian citizen, for what it's worth, and I am not a Hong Kong citizen/resident.

See a [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/12771/17245).

Comment: How are you currently employed by the Hong Kong company? Presumably you have the right to work in HK if employed by the HK company? If you retain this right you should be able to continue to work for them regardless of where you are in the world.

Comment: I have a 2-year type U "employment" visa. Since asking this question I have realized that the sticky part of this would be Australia. I don't know whether I could continue working for a foreign country while in AU on a working holiday visa, but it doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would count because there is no exception listed.

The key part off [the government's website](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/417.aspx):

> If you hold a Working Holiday visa, **the main purpose of your visit
>   must be for an extended holiday**. You can do any kind of work over the
>   course of your 12 month stay in Australia, however all Working Holiday
>   visa holders are limited to a maximum period of six months work with
>   any one employer. This limitation applies to all employers and all
>   forms of work.

If you're still actively engaged in work for your existing employer, it would not be a holiday as such.  You could also fall afoul of the six month limitation on single employers.  The employment (max of six months with one employer) and study limitations (max four months) are designed to ensure that people have the correct form of visa.

Given your description of the situation, if you intend to continue working for your current employer [a 12 month Visitor visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/600.aspx) would be more appropriate as it does not enforce limitations on your employment.