# Does an ESTA cover a self-employed UK citizen, contracted by an Australian company for US work?

Tags: usa, esta, uk-citizens

I have been contracted by an Australian-based company to do three weeks' work around the United States. I am a UK citizen, self-employed and will be paid into a UK bank account by said Australian company.

Is this possible to do on an ESTA?

Answer (score 4):

**Not legally**: working in the US requires a work visa, full stop.

See also: [I want to travel to the USA while working remotely for my non-US employer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/i-want-to-travel-to-the-usa-while-working-remotely-for-my-non-us-employer)