# Do I need a working visa to stay in the US but work for a company in Europe?

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, work

Sorry If this seems a silly question but I am 19 and have never delved into anything like this before. I am a software developer and have plans soon  to work remotely as quite a few companies offer this (adhering to their time zone requirements ) and I would quite like to mix work in with travel. What kind of visas / requirements would I need to stay in the United states for say, 6 months to 1 year, and what are my first steps?

Comment: Broadly speaking: to do this legally is much more difficult than you may think or expect.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/i-want-to-travel-to-the-usa-while-working-remotely-for-my-non-us-employer

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer will depend on which technicality you apply.

Comment: This has been discussed here in the past, and it seems that if I book a hotel room in most countries and spend my time in the room drinking beer, and you book the hotel room next door and spend your time in the room writing software for your company at home, then you need a work visa, and I don't. Even though nobody could detect what we are both doing.