# Work remotely from US under L2 visa with my UK employer while awaiting EAD

Tags: visas, working-visas, remote-locations

My husband is moving to the US permanently with an L-1 visa, and my daughter and I are moving with him with L-2 dependant visas. Currently I am employed in the UK and I will apply to get the EAD (work permit) as soon as I arrive in the US. My current employer in the UK has offered me to work remotely for a couple of months until I get the EAD. Is this allowed? Do I need to get any permits? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I travel to the USA while working remotely for my non-US employer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/can-i-travel-to-the-usa-while-working-remotely-for-my-non-us-employer)

Comment: _Thank you all for your input as it helped me a lot. Just to follow up on how it went down if anyone is interested, I had no issues at the border control at US. I had a letter from my employer prepared in case it was required but it wasn't needed. Border protection agent did raise the question of why coming in to US shores for such a long period and they were satisfied with my answer which was to visit the country while working remotely for my overseas employer_

Comment: Don't forget to think about the tax implications.

Comment: My visa case is different, as I am asking whether I can work on remote for a couple of months while having the L2 resident visa until I get the EAD approved. The case stated above is for a person who wants to work remotely while on a tourist visa.

Comment: IMHO there is no material difference. From the answer you can work remotely for any non USA company whatever status you’re on in the USA. Visitors visas have the most restrictions concerning any type of work.