# Can a B2 Visitor in the USA work for a UK company as a consultant, performing work for a US company

Tags: usa, legal, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, work

Jane and Alan live in the UK, they are engaged to be married, they are NOT married.

Alan receives a job offer in the US and is granted an o1 Visa.

Because they are not married, Jane is given a B2 visa so she may go with Alan.

Jane is employed by a UK company as a consultant. That UK company are hired by a US company and Jane is given that workload.

Jane is now living in the USA, consulting for a UK company, doing work for a US company.

Is this legal?

Comment: Even if you remove the “doing work for a US company” I don’t believe that’s legal. She’s not allowed to work, full stop. And she’s not allowed to “live in the USA” either, only visit. You need to reconsider the whole situation.

Comment: @jcaron B-2 visas are sometimes granted to people for extended stays.  The common case is that of a family member who accompanies someone in another visa class, but who does not qualify for a dependent visa.  That is the case here.  With such a B-2 visa, it is indeed permitted to "live in the USA."  See [9 FAM 402.2-4(B)(5)  (U) Cohabitating Partners, Extended Family Members, and Other Household Members not Eligible for Derivative Status](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040202.html#M402_2_4_B_5).

Comment: @jcaron quoting: "The B-2 classification is appropriate for aliens who are members of the household of another alien in long-term nonimmigrant status, but who are not eligible for derivative status under that alien's visa classification." Later: "If such individuals plan to stay in the United States for more than six months, you should advise them to ask DHS for a one-year stay at the time they apply for admission.  If needed, they may thereafter apply for extensions of stay, in increments of up to six months, for the duration of the principal alien's nonimmigrant status in the United States."

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:**

Jane cannot work in the US while she is in B-2 status.

**Long Answer**

US Visa B-2 is for tourism. [This travel.state.gov page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html#overview) says permitted activities on a B-2 visa include:

> - Tourism
> - Vacation (holiday)
> - Visit with friends or relatives
> - Medical treatment
> - Participation in social events hosted by fraternal, social, or service organizations
> - Participation by amateurs in musical, sports, or similar events or contests, if not being paid for participating
> - Enrollment in a short recreational course of study, not for credit toward a degree (for example, a two-day cooking class while on vacation)

Just below on the same State Department page this appears:

> Travel Purposes Not Permitted on Visitor Visas
>
> - Study
> - **Employment**
> - Paid performances, or any professional performance before a paying audience
> - Arrival as a crewmember on a ship or aircraft
>   Work as foreign press, in radio, film, print journalism, or other information media
> - Permanent residence in the United States

Thus, Jane is not permitted to work while in the US in B-2 status.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the correction. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to line up with some other answers to similar questions, for example the answer to this question here:

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/can-i-travel-to-the-usa-while-working-remotely-for-my-non-us-employer

The purpose of Janes visit is not employment. Jane is employed in the UK and the question is, is it legal for her to work for her company while in the US. Jane would not be employed by a US company though her consultancy work for a UK firm may result in working with a US company.

Comment: @Gandeh I suppose you're thinking about the accepted answer to that question, which essentially says that you can do it without being detected or that short periods of incidental work-related activity such as taking phone calls and checking e-mail are permitted.  Did you see the [answer with the most upvotes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/31025/19400)? "My visa was immediately rejected when I mentioned that I was planning to work for a German company while in the States, with the reasoning that I was planning to work there."

Comment: @Gandeh or [the next answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/60870/19400)? "I was denied a visa by telling I may work remotely while on US..."  If Jane would be eligible to travel to the US as a B-1 visitor (or in some other nonimmigrant status) to do this work, then she might be able to file a change-of-status application to do the work lawfully.  But this answer is correct: she cannot do it while she is in B-2 status.

Comment: @phoog I did see that one also, the trouble I'm having is separating individual immigration officers judgement from the law. Everything seems to be open to a large amount of interpretation. And certainly you would have to assume that lots of B2 visitors are taking work calls and answering email.

Comment: I think the crucial point I'm trying to illustrate is that her purpose of travel is not work. The purpose of travel is as the unmarried partner and mother of Alans child. Alan holding an o1 visa and the child holding an o3.

But if she holds UK employment that is remote work, can it be done legally?

Comment: @Gandeh but the point here is that she wouldn't be working incidentally during a short visit, she would be performing all of her work in the US while living there for an extended "visit."  If you'd rather have citations of statutory or regulatory provisions instead of a public-information page from the State Department, I imagine that DavidSupportsMonica can edit the answer to provide that, since he is a lawyer.  But that probably won't help, because it's a horrible gray area that has been the subject of court cases for decades.  There won't be any way to escape officer discretion entirely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111929/discussion-between-phoog-and-gandeh).