# Can Canadian PR holder work from USA for few days while on vacation?

Tags: usa, canada, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, canadian-permanent-residents

I am a Permanent Resident in Canada working for a Canadian Employer. I want to travel to the US as a B1/B2 visa holder for one week and work from home for my Canadian employer for 4 days from the US while I visit some friends and family in my free time. I will not be taking any vacation during these 4 working days. Is this allowed legally and can there be any questions/legal implications in the future regarding this travel time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a B2 Visitor in the USA work for a UK company as a consultant, performing work for a US company](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158900/can-a-b2-visitor-in-the-usa-work-for-a-uk-company-as-a-consultant-performing-wo) Read all the responses, including the comments that follow the answer.

Comment: **Legally** working on B1/B2 is not allowed. Whether ICE is going to follow you around and track what you do with your laptop at your friends' guest room - that's a different question. Both you and your employer may get into trouble with the US government if you get caught though.