# Is it possible to travel to the USA on an B1/B2 visa while contracting remotely for a US company?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

I have just been offered a remote contracting job by a US company. I live in the UK and I visit the USA often on a B1/B2.

I want to know if it will be legal for me to visit the USA while contracting for and being paid this company.

Technically they would be contracting me through my own company and I would be getting paid through an LLC based in the UK but this feels like it could be non compliant or potentially fall into a legal grey area.

I would really love to be able to visit friends while also working but I’m not sure if this is possible.

Comment: It’s possible but against immigration law. The USA doesn’t want you working while visiting the USA, period. Of course many visitors answer work entails and sometimes even put in some work on projects while on vacation. However bottom line, USA immigration is against that. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/can-i-travel-to-the-usa-while-working-remotely-for-my-non-us-employer#:~:text=Tourist%20visas%20do%20not%20allow,is%20not%20under%20any%20penalty.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So if I travelled there I’d presumably have to take a vacation from work and resume work after returning to the UK.

Answer (score 4):

Visa status is based on purpose of the visit not your state of employment. B1/B2 visa is for tourism, business meetings etc. As long as this is what you are intending to do - there should be no issue. On the other hand B1/B2 is non-work visa - so you are not allowed to work in US.