# Do I need a work visa or is an ESTA ok for a short trip to the US

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, esta, b1-b2-visas

I am going to the US for tourism for 16 days but will be working for my UK employer for 7 out of the 16 days. Will I need to get a Work Visa for my duration or am I ok to travel with just the ESTA?

Comment: What sort of work will you be doing in the US?  You won't be eligible for a work visa, but if the activities are permissible for a business visitor then you can enter with the visa waiver program (i.e., with ESTA).  If the activities are actually "work" then they are not permitted for a business visitor and you will not be able to realize your plan.  Unfortunately, the line between "work" and "business" is rather blurred.

Comment: I would expect your employer to give you information on visas, particularly if you are a salaried employee. If they are sending you on business as part of a contract with a US company or otherwise in the course of your work, they should ensure you meet travel requirements, as it's not in their interests for you to be refused entry, and if appropriate they should contact a lawyer or other expert (even if you have to apply personally for travel documents). As phoog says, for some purposes (e.g. attending business meetings) you can travel on an ESTA, but this may not always be the case.

Comment: @phoog thanks for the reply. It’s remote work so I will be continuing work with my company (i.e. attending meetings and completing work on my side) I am not being sent to the US by my company for any purpose, it’s a personal trip I just want to be able to continue work while I’m there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I travel to the USA while working remotely for my non-US employer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/can-i-travel-to-the-usa-while-working-remotely-for-my-non-us-employer)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella there are two problems with that duplicate, the first being that the highly upvoted accepted answer is in fact incorrect, and the second being that this trip is 16 days instead of 3 to 6 months.  It's much easier to work remotely "under the radar" for a week and a half out of a 2-week trip than it is to do so during a 3-to-6-month trip.

Comment: @Amana Is it your company requiring you to work while on your 16 day vacation or are you trying to get a 16 day vacation while taking fewer actual vacation days?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not eligible for a work visa as these are for people working for US companies.

The visa waiver program (VWP), commonly but imprecisely referred to as "ESTA," permits visitors to enter both "for pleasure" and "for business."  These are the categories corresponding to B-2 and B-1 status, respectively.

I doubt you would qualify as a business visitor, because you aren't traveling to the US for business reasons.  Instead, you are traveling as a tourist and would like to engage in incidental activity relating to your job during your trip.  whether this is permitted depends on the nature of the activity.

For example, it is certainly permissible for a tourist (more precisely, "visitor for pleasure") in the US to have phone conversations and e-mail and other communication with work colleagues.  It is also certainly not permissible for a tourist to manufacture or sell tangible goods in the US on behalf of a foreign employer.

"Attending meetings" is probably acceptable, but "completing work" is probably not.  Canada explicitly allows remote work, but many countries, including the US, have not updated their policies to reflect the present-day reality of remote work.  Your best bet is to avoid doing any substantive work while you are in the US and not to mention the possibility of working remotely if you speak with any US officials.